# Perl string weirdness : equal strings being not equal?

Tags: string, perl, debugging

I am using Perl v5.16.2

I am using the Net::SMPP modules and it returns me some data.
If I show this data, I get this (simplified) :

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'receipted_message_id' => '400002F6E09C61701222120140',
                 '30' => '400002F6E09C61701222120140'
               }, 'Net::SMPP::PDU' );
```

Now, let's assume this data is in $pdu and I do this :

```
$message_id = $pdu->{30}; # or $pdu->{receipted_message_id}, same result
myfunction($message_id);
```

Then, I have myfunction defined as :

```
sub myfunction {
    my $message_id = shift; 
    my $message_id_static = '400002F6E09C61701222120140';

    print Dumper($message_id);
    print Dumper($message_id_static);

    print hexdump($message_id);
    print hexdump($message_id_static);

    if ($message_id eq $message_id_static)
    {
        print "match\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}
```

The output of the program is :

```
$VAR1 = '400002F6E09C61701222120140';
$VAR1 = '400002F6E09C61701222120140';
Data::Hexdumper: data length isn't an integer multiple of lines
so has been padded with NULLs at the end.
  0x0000 : 34 30 30 30 30 32 46 36 45 30 39 43 36 31 37 30 : 400002F6E09C6170
  0x0010 : 31 32 32 32 31 32 30 31 34 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 1222120140......
Data::Hexdumper: data length isn't an integer multiple of lines
so has been padded with NULLs at the end.
  0x0000 : 34 30 30 30 30 32 46 36 45 30 39 43 36 31 37 30 : 400002F6E09C6170
  0x0010 : 31 32 32 32 31 32 30 31 34 30 00 00 00 00 00 00 : 1222120140......
no match
```

Which doesn't make any sense to me... !
If I try to use $message_id to do a SQLite query, it fails miserably. If I use $message_id_static instead, it works perfectly.

So, is this a weird internal Perl bug, or am I missing something ?
This has been driving me nuts for hours...

**EDIT :**

Using the perl debugger, I get this :

```
  DB<3> x $message_id_static
0  '400002F6E09C61701222120140'
  DB<4> x $message_id
0  "400002F6E09C61701222120140\c@"
```

So at least I see there is a difference in the strings, but why isn't it seen by the hexdump, and what is that \c@ ?

Thanks !

Comment: Couldn't that be garbage in the source file?

Comment: `\c@` is probably a representation of Ctrl-@, which is the null character. C treats the null character as an end-of-string marker. Perl generally doesn't, but *something* seems to be handling null characters incorrectly.

Comment: What error do you get when you use `$message_id` in SQLite? Any chance this isn't a plain scalar text but an object / hash reference? The code you pasted worked for me, but it dos not have the `$message_id`. Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to show the problem?

Comment: Hi, Keith is right, it was a null character. Thanks very much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\c@` character is Ctrl-@, which is the ASCII NUL character at code point zero

You can't see it in your `hexdump` output because it is indistinguishable from the `00` padding at the end of the dump

If you set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` then it will be visible in the output from `print Dumper $message_id`

You can remove it from the variable by using `s/\0\z//` or `tr/\0//d`, but you should really investigate why it is there in the first place

Comment: Really unfortunate coincidence that Data::Hexdumper decides to do that, instead of just cutting the line short at the end like `xxd`.

Comment: @hobbs: Yes, it's really poor design

Comment: Hi, yes it was a null character. I got rid of it with a regexp. Thank you very much !